# Getting error template error while templating string: No filter named 'json_query'

Tags: installation, ansible, runtime-error, jmespath, json-query

With this playbook

```yaml
---
- name: ReadJsonfile
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    
    - name: Display the JSON file content
      shell: "cat config.json"
      register: result

    - name: save the Json data to a Variable as a Fact
      set_fact:
        jsondata: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: setDomainName
      set_fact:
        domain_name: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
      vars:
        jmesquery: '[].domain[].name'
```

There are two users on my Linux server: `user1` and `user2`

`python3.8`, `pip`, `ansible-core`, `ansible-base` & `jmespath` were installed.

I login with `user1`  and the above playbook runs fine

`ansible-playbook test.yml`

However, when I login with `user2` and run the same I get the below error

> TASK [setDomainName]
> ****************************************************************************************** Monday 21 March 2022  01:16:40 -0500 (0:00:00.140)       0:00:04.221
> ********** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'json_query'.. String: {{
> jsondata | json_query(jmesquery) }}"}

**Note:** When run with `user1` the playbook works fine. The error is when run with `user2` only.

Is there something wrong with the way I setup things with `user2`?

Below are the details for `user2`

```
[user2@myhost Migrator]$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user2/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user2/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.12 (default, Mar 21 2022, 00:59:19) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True


[user2@myhost Migrator]$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook [core 2.12.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user2/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user2/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user2/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.12 (default, Mar 21 2022, 00:59:19) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True

[user2@myhost Migrator]$ pip --version
bash: pip: command not found

[user2@myhost Migrator]$ pip3 --version
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 21.3.1 from /home/user2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

[user2@myhost Migrator]$ pip3 install jmespath
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.10.0)
[user2@myhost Migrator]$

[user2@myhost Migrator]$ python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.12
```

JmesPath was installed as below:

```
$ sudo pip3.8 install jmespath
Collecting jmespath
  Downloading jmespath-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Installing collected packages: jmespath
Successfully installed jmespath-1.0.0
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

Can you please suggest a solution to the issue?

Comment: have you installed jmespath? its not included in the ansible package...

Comment: Seems so .. i have updated the Original Post with `pip3 install jmespath` output. Can you please check if thats where the issue is?

Comment: You most probably are missing the `community.general` collection on `user2` when it is installed for `user1`. To confirm: `ls -la /home/user2/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community && ls -la /home/user1/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community`. To install it if it is missing, as `user2`: `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε `/home/user2/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community` was not found for both the users yet the playbook works for `user1`.  I still went ahead with your suggestion of installing `community.general` and the error is resolved !!. Please post as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you did install Ansible with the pip packages `ansible-core` & `ansible-base`, you don't have the collection `community.general`, which this filter is part of.

You have multiple options:

1. Install the missing collection, when logged in with the problematic user:

   ```sh
   ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
   ```
2. Install the full Ansible package:

   ```sh
   pip uninstall ansible-core ansible-base
   pip install ansible
   ```
3. Reinstall the collection in the shared folder, with the option `-p`

   ```sh
   ansible-galaxy collection install community.general \
       -p /usr/share/ansible/collections
   ```